# How to retrieve form field that is configured "mapped" => false in Symfony Form?

Tags: symfony

How to retrieve form field that is configured `"mapped" => false` and is NOT part of form ENTITY in Symfony Form?

After form submitted form object does not contain field that is configured as `"mapped" => false` named *mainCheckbox*.

Form Builder:

```
class DocumentCategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Podkategoria'))
            ->add('mainCheckbox', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Kategoria główna',
                "mapped" => false,
            ))
            ->add('parentId', EntityType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Kategoria główna',
                'class' => IntraDocumentCategory::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->where('c.parentId = :parent')
                        ->setParameter('parent', 0);},
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Dodaj'));
    }
```

Controller:

```
$documentCategory = new IntraDocumentCategory();
$form = $this->createForm(DocumentCategoryType::class, $documentCategory);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $formData = $form->getData();
```

While debuging `$formData` is an object of `AppBundle\Entity\IntraDocumentCategory` and contain only their fields, not *mainCheckbox* from form builder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the form fields with the following syntax:

```
$form->get('mainCheckbox')->getData();
```

If the field is present then you should get the value of that field.